# Change method return type according to a parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following method for opening and deserializing an XML file:

```
private static object DeserializeFile(string fileName, Type type)
{
    Stream openFile = TitleContainer.OpenStream(fileName);
    XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(type);
    return reader.Deserialize(openFile);
}
```

I use it various times to open different files containing different objects. At the moment I have to use it in the following way:

```
City gameCity = (City)DeserializeFile(GameData.CITIES_FILE, typeof(City));
```

I have a feeling that the typecast can be avoided by making the method return an object casted to the type passed in as a parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution's actually pretty simple:

```
private static T DeserializeFile<T>(string fileName)
{
    Stream openFile = TitleContainer.OpenStream(fileName);
    XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)reader.Deserialize(openFile);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
City gameCity = DeserializeFile<City>(GameData.CITIES_FILE);
```